# O que é o rel=”noopener”? Devo usa-lo em todos os links do meu site? Ele pode afetar o SEO?

Tags: html, html5, navegador-de-internet, seo

Recentemente notei que o a propriedade `rel` do *link* pode receber o tributo `noopener`, mas não entendi direito as vantagens de usa-lo...

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Exemplo de link</a>
```

Seria uma boa prática incluir esse `rel="noopener"` em todos os links do meu site?

Ele pode ter algum efeito colateral indesejado para o SEO?

Comment: se até o @hugocsl toma um -1, isso me acalma hehehehe, ocara já respondeu

Comment: @Ricardo o engraçado eh que tem 3 dias a pergunta, ai quando alguém tem a boa vontade de colaborar com algum conteúdo alguém vai e me da um negativo rss. Vai entender...

Comment: Puro recalque! Kkkk! Não imaginava que poderia usar o window.opener dessa forma!

Comment: @LipESprY infelizmente aqui tem esse tipo de coisa... Mas o importante eh contribuir esse tipo de coisa eh irrelevante, um comentário ou dica, ou critica eh 10x mais construtivo que um downvote, mas tem pessoas que preferem esconder a cara atrás dos downvotes, que muito pouco ou quase nada fazem com que alguma coisa melhore no conteúdo. Já quando vc da uma dica pessoal ou critica mesmo, vc abre um canal de comunicação, diferente de um voto de desqualificação que pouco quer dizer...

Comment: Se afeta o rankeamento e quanto ninguém sabe né, mas no lighthouse (web.dev) links externos com `_blank`  tiram pontos  em boas práticas e sugere `noopener` como solução.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/noopener?hl=pt-br

Comment: @gustavox o Lighthouse realmente eh uma ferramenta fantástica eh não só para SEO, mas para acessibilidade e performance tbm. Valeu a dica!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem isso, a nova página pode acessar seu objeto de janela via window.opener. Felizmente, o modelo de segurança de origem da web impede que ele leia sua página; infelizmente, para algumas API legadas significa que é possível navegar na página para um URL diferente usando window.opener.location = newURL.

A maioria dos navegadores é multiprocesso — com a exceção do Firefox, mas eles estão trabalhando nisso. Cada processo possui várias threads, incluindo o que frequentemente é chamado de “a thread principal”. É aí que a análise, o cálculo do estilo, o layout, o painting de CSS e o JavaScript (não-worker) são executados. Isso significa que JavaScript executado em um domínio é executado em uma thread diferente para uma janela/guia acessando outro domínio.

No entanto, devido ao acesso síncrono cross-window que o DOM provê via window.opener, janelas executadas via target="_blank" acabam no mesmo processo e thread — e o mesmo é verdadeiro para iframes e janelas abertas via window.open.

rel="noopener" impede window.opener, portanto não há acesso cross-window. Navegadores Chromium são otimizados para isso e abrem a nova página em seu próprio processo.

Em outras palavras, ao usar rel="noopener" em links externos, especifica-se que o acesso deve ser feito em outro processo, trazendo benefícios nas áreas de segurança e performance!

Por enquanto, ainda não é algo suportado em absolutamente todos os navegadores, mas a ideia é que estes benefícios sejam logo vistos pelos vendors e que seus produtos estejam preparados para o noopener o quanto antes isso acontecer. Também, é possível que no futuro existam maneiras mais práticas de, por exemplo, especificar que todos os links devam obedecer esta feature sem a necessidade de especificar link a link.

Fonte: https://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/miscelanea/relnoopener-performance-seguranca/

Comment: Amigo quando vc copiar textos completos de outros lugares ou mesmo que sejam partes de um texto que não eh seu vc deveria no mínimo citar a fonte ou o autor original ok. Abs boas festas

Comment: @hugocsl Obrigado, fonte mencionada.